# How can I keep form updated without reloading DOM?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, ecmascript-6, nedb

I have an app that works perfectly and keeps the form updated but only if I reload the DOM. Is it possible to update a form with newly input or user modified data without reloading it when someone clicks submit button?

**Server Code:**

```
"use strict";

const DATA_HANDLER = require('./node/DataHandler');

class app {
     constructor() {
          this.ejsData = null;
          this.nedbData = new DATA_HANDLER();
          this.nedbData.loadData((docs) => {
               this.ejsData = docs;
          });
          this.loadServer();
     }

     loadServer() {
          const HTTP = require('http'),
               EJS = require('ejs'),
               PORT = 1337,
               SERVER = HTTP.createServer((req, res) => {
                    let httpHandler = (err, str, contentType) => {
                         if (err) {
                              res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
                              res.end('An error has occurred: ' + err.message);
                         } else if (contentType.indexOf('image') >= 0) {
                              res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                              res.end(str, 'binary');
                         } else if (contentType.indexOf('html') >= 0) {
                              res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                              res.end(EJS.render(str, {
                                   data: this.ejsData,
                                   filename: 'index.ejs' }));
                         } else {
                              res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                              res.end(str, 'utf-8');
                         }
                    };

                    if (req.method == 'POST') {
                         if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
                              this.loadData(req, res, 0);
                         } else if (req.headers['x-requested-load'] === 'XMLHttpRequest1') {
                              this.loadData(req, res, 1);
                         } else {
                              console.log("[405] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
                              res.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                              res.end('<html><head><title>405 - Method not supported</title></head><body><h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>');
                         }
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/javascripts/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'application/ecmascript', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/css/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'text/css', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    } else if (req.url.indexOf('/images/') >= 0) {
                         this.render(req.url.slice(1), 'image/jpeg', httpHandler, 'binary');
                    } else {
                         this.render('public/views/index.ejs', 'text/html', httpHandler, 'utf-8');
                    }
               }).listen(PORT, _ => console.log('-= Work Order Server Listening at http://127.0.0.1:' + PORT + ' =-'));
     }

     render(path, contentType, callback, encoding) {
          const FS = require('fs');
          FS.readFile(__dirname + '/' + path, encoding ? encoding : 'utf-8', (err, str) => { // ternary
               callback(err, str, contentType);
          });
     }

     loadData(req, res, whichAjax) {
          if (whichAjax === 1) {
               const FORMIDABLE = require('formidable');
               let formData = {};
               new FORMIDABLE.IncomingForm().parse(req).on('field', (field, name) => {
                    formData[field] = name;
               }).on('error', (err) => {
                    next(err);
               }).on('end', () => {
                    this.nedbData.queryData(formData);
               });
          }
          this.nedbData.loadData((docs) => {
               let jsonDocs = JSON.stringify(docs);
               res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
               res.end(jsonDocs);
               this.ejsData = docs;
          });
     }
}

module.exports = app;
```

**Data Handler:**

```
 "use strict";

    const DATASTORE = require('nedb');
    let DB = new DATASTORE({ filename: './data/workorder_db.json', autoload: true });
         this.data = [];

    class DataHandler {
        constructor() {
              DB.loadDatabase();
        }

         loadData(callback) {
              DB.find({}, (err, docs) => {
                   if (docs.length != null) {
                        callback(docs);
                   }
              });
         }

         updateData(data) {
              DB.update({ _id: data.id }, { building: data.building
                   , roomNumber: data.roomNumber
                   , submitter: data.submitter
                   , problemDesc: data.problemDesc
                   , assigned: data.assigned
                   , completed: data.completed
                   , status: data.status
                   , date: data.date
              }, { upsert: true,
                   returnUpdatedDocs: true });
         }

         addData(data) {
              delete data.id;  // remove id field out of JSON parameter
              DB.insert(data);
         }

         queryData(data) {
              DB.findOne({ _id: data.id }, (err, docs) => {
                   if (docs == null) {
                        this.addData(data);
                   } else {
                        this.updateData(data);
                   }
              });
         }
    }

    module.exports = DataHandler;
```

**EJS File:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <h4>Current Work:</h4>
        <table>
            <% if (data.length > 0) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Building</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Room #</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Challenge</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Assignment</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <% for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= data[i].date %></td>
                        <td><%= data[i].building %></td>
                        <td><%= data[i].roomNumber %></td>
                        <td><%= data[i].problemDesc %></td>
                        <td><%= data[i].assigned %></td>
                        <td><%= data[i].status %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% } %>
            <% } %>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still struggling with this one. It appears to be related to how NeDB returns data even after reloading the database.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ajax, here's a general scheme for keeping your form up to date:

1. Make an Ajax call from client to server, asking the server if it has any updated data.
2. If the server has updated data, it returns that data (probably in JSON format).
3. When the client receives the data, it can then insert the changed data directly into the existing form using DOM manipulation functions (no reload).
4. The client can then set a timer and repeat this process at some regular time interval.

Using webSockets, here's a general scheme for keeping your form up to date:

1. As part of the page load, the page creates a webSocket connection to the server.
2. On the server, whenever new data for the form is available, the server can just send that data to the connected client over the webSocket.
3. When the client receives the data via the webSocket (same JSON as the above option), it can then insert the changed data directly into the existing form using DOM manipulation functions (no reload).

Because the client/server are continuously connected with the webSocket, there is no need for a timer or continuous polling as in the Ajax option.

---

You don't show your form HTML so we can't advise specifically on how to do your form manipulations, but here's an example:

```
<form>
    <input id="someField">
</form>

// put new value into input field
document.getElementById("someField").value = myNewValue;
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems as though NeDB appends the new or updated entries to the bottom of the database, then when you reload the database, it puts everything where it belongs. I think this is what is stopping me....?